# Using bcrypt derived keys for encryption?

Tags: encryption, hmac, pbkdf-2, bcrypt, sha-512

Sorry for this ignorant question but I am currently weighing up the advantages and disadvantages of BCrypt over PBKDF2 and from what I have read BCrypt is considered more secure but from what I have discovered BCrypt only derives as 248-bit key (Example: E2cP18g8DyWwg3emgpHOaPBZzrcRVrO) and the rest of it is the salt, however I require a 512-bit key so I can split it into two sub-keys on for a AES encryption key and the other for HMAC generation.

Would it be secure to take the sha-512 hash of the key produced by BCrypt and split that or should I just keep using PBKDF2?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 248-bit number?

Comment: Why not just run bcrypt twice with a different salt?

Comment: @mikeazo because the 248 bit key would still be to small for a AES-256 encryption key and I'm not sure if this is what you asked for but when I run bcrypt it returns {salt}{248-bit key}

Comment: First, the output of bcrypt is not a 248-bit key. It is 192-bit value encoded as base-64, which is why it is 248-bits. What are your requirements for the 512-bit key. Just that it is 512-bits long and uniformly distributed? Or do you require that it have a certain amount of entropy? Or is there something else? I'm assuming you are considering bcrypt and pbkdf2 so that brute force is slow. Is that correct?

Comment: @mikeazo yes I did consider using PBKDF2 or Bcrypt fot that exact reason my only requirement is that it is 512-bits long and would be suitable for encrypting a file and generating a hmac of said encrypted file (One 256-bit of the key would be used as a encryption key the other as a hmac key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BCrypt is considered more secure

The theoretical security of bcrypt has received less scrutiny than that of PBKDF2, SHA2 and HMAC.  PBKDF2 is thus widely standardised (e.g. in [NIST SP800-132](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-132/nist-sp800-132.pdf) and [PKCS #5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898)) while bcrypt is not.

In practice the security (resistance to brute force attack or dictionary attack) of bcrypt and PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512 can be controlled by a workload parameter.  bcrypt is more secure than PBKDF2 in the sense that: if you select the workload parameters such that the algorithms use the same computing *time* on a general-purpose CPU, then an attacker able to choose their hardware (CPU, GPU, FPGA, or ASIC) can attack PBKDF2 4 to 6 times more effectively than bcrypt *at the same cost* (see the [scrypt paper](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf)).

As a heuristic we could say that a password hashed with PBKDF2 should have 2 to 3 bits more randomness than a password hashed with bcrypt to achieve equivalent security (against a brute force attack; for equivalent workload parameters).

> Would it be secure to take the sha-512 hash of the key produced by BCrypt and split that

No, but you're on the right path by splitting the operation into a step that produces a key, and a step that expands the key.  The trick is to select the right primitives for these operations.

To expand a key - that is, to produce using one key a stream of derived random output suitable for use as key material - you need a [Pseudorandom Function Family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) (PRF).  SHA-512 is not a PRF, but HMAC-SHA512 is.  Using HMAC-SHA512 would be a secure - but not ideal - solution.

A better solution is to use [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) which splits key derivation into extraction and expansion steps.  By using bcrypt or PBKDF2 you have already extracted a pseudorandom key (HKDF calls this a PRK) from the password.  You can apply the HKDF expansion step to that PRK to produce derived keying material of any length; equivalently you could use one of the Key Derivation Functions from [NIST SP800-108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf).

See also [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage) for more on PBKDF2 vs bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use bcrypt in this scenario. The output of bcrypt is 192-bits encoded using base-64, giving you 248-bits. Well short of your 512-bit requirement.

What I would recommend you do, if you choose bcrypt, is akin to what was recommended [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/how-to-salt-pbkdf2-when-generating-both-an-aes-key-and-a-hmac-key-for-encrypt-t). Use HMAC instead of SHA-512 of the output of bcrypt. For the reasons why, see [this question and answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13232/how-is-hkdf-expand-better-than-a-simple-hash/). It is important to understand though that since the output of crypt is smaller than 256-bits, neither of your keys will have 256-bits of entropy. It sounds like you aren't too worried about that though.

As to bcrypt in this manner vs. simply using PBKDF2 with SHA-512, that depends on what you are worried about. PBKDF2 can more easily be attacked using things like [GPUs and FPGAs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage).

Comment: One final question so im sure I understand completely so would i? 1:Generate a "Master Key" using Bcrypt. 2:Then split the master key. 3:Use one half of the "master key" as a HMAC-SHA512 key to generate the encryption key. 4:Use the other half of the "master key" as a HMAC-SHA512 key to generate the key for the actual HMAC of the encrypted data?

Comment: No, use the entire master key for both, but use a different "message" for HMAC.